# Mongodb: Update nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to update a nested array since forever, but still cannot figure out how to do it properly.
I have a document looking like this:

```
    "inv": {
    "id01": {
      "n": "apple",
      "active": "false"
    },
    "id02": {
      "n": "banana",
      "active": "false"
    },
    "id03": {
      "n": "orange",
      "active": "false"
    },
    "id04": {
      "n": "greenapple",
      "active": "false"
}
    }
```

now I want to update the existing elements in the array with this

```
 "id02": {
  "n": "banana",
  "active": "true"
},
"id03": {
  "n": "cherry",
  "active": "true"
}
```

but if I update it using using this

```
db.get().collection('userdata').updateOne({username: ws.id}, {$set:{inv: newdata}})
```

other elements like `id01`, `id04` get deleted.

I think this is the way to do it:

```
db.get().collection('userdata').updateOne({username:ws.id}, {$set:{inv.id01: newdata}})
```

but i need a more dynamic way by not having the exact id in the key . Could anyone help me to come up with a solution for this?? Thank you!!!

Comment: look into arrayFilters

Comment: I think this video will solve you problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPPUAUk9I-w

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dot operator to update the spefic field.

```
db.test.updateOne({username: "u1"}, {$set:{"inv.id02.active": true, "inv.id03.active":true}})
```

This will update the collection, to append new items to `inv` you need to set the entire `inv` key as you've described.

Comment: i know this would be the solution but is there any way to not include the id in the key so it could work with any incoming data? inv.i̶d̶0̶2̶.active.
What if the received data is id06, id07,... it won't work, right?